javax.servlet.api dependency not found in WildFly deployment without using an IDE (jboss/wildfly)
I am encountering a problem with my WildFly server deployment where the javax.servlet.api dependency is not being recognized despite having Undertow enabled. Below are the details of my setup and the issue.
Environment:
WildFly Version: 11.0.0.Final
Java Version: OpenJDK 1.8.0_201
Operating System: Windows 10
Problem Description:
I am trying to deploy a WAR file (test_html.war) on WildFly. Even though Undertow is active and should provide javax.servlet.api implicitly, my deployment fails with a NoClassDefFoundError for HttpServletResponse. Here are some excerpts from the server logs that highlight the issue
I believe the issue might be due to the basic server runtime not being able to find javax.servlet.api. The deployment works when the server runtime is set up in Eclipse, but I need to achieve this without using an IDE.
Why is the javax.servlet.api dependency not being recognized even though Undertow is active?
What additional configurations or steps are required to ensure that the servlet API is available for my application?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Standalone Server Logs:
2024-05-17 08:34:34,409 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.Final starting
2024-05-17 08:34:34,669 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2024-05-17 08:34:34,672 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2024-05-17 08:34:34,699 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080

Error Details:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HttpServletResponse
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletResponse from [Module "deployment.test_html.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 51 more

jboss-deployment-structure.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.ejb.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="org.picketbox" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
        <module name="javax.faces.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>


It looks like something is trying to reference HttpServletResponse not javax.http.HttpServletResponse. You also don't need that jboss-deployment-structure.xml. You may also need to verify that your WAR is not including any of the Java EE API libraries.
